# UIBezierPath Triangle reverse

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

Currently I am having a small issue. The code below will output an triangle shaped layer on top of my tableViewHeader but I want to reverse the cut direction of the bazier path.

**Code:**

```
let cutDirection = UIBezierPath()
cutDirection.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height - headerCut))
newHeaderLayer.path = cutDirection.cgPath
```

**Outputs:**

[image]

[image]

**Result I am looking for:**

Thanks for any help!

Kevin.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @rmaddy I wanted to reverse the cut Direction. Fixed it already!

Comment: What you wanted was clear. But your question was not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let cutDirection = UIBezierPath()
cutDirection.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height - headerCut))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height))
newHeaderLayer.path = cutDirection.cgPath
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow this correctly you should swap the following:

```
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height - headerCut))
```

To:

```
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height - headerCut))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height))
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by doing it the old school way: On Paper!

**Solution:**

```
let cutDirection = UIBezierPath()
cutDirection.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: 0))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: headerRect.width, y: headerRect.height - headerCut))
cutDirection.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: headerRect.height))
cutDirection.close()
newHeaderLayer.path = cutDirection.cgPath
```